# Визуальное изменение Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема следующая: 
Как видите, слева от нумерации строк белый прямоугольник, который мне совсем не нужен. Я только перешёл с IDEA и пытаюсь нормально настроить среду, может кто-нибудь подсказать, как его убрать или хотя бы перекрасить в подходящий цвет?

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите на тему Moonrise: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme

Comment: Но там тоже слева от нумерации есть место для расстановки брекпойнтов, отметок TODO итп.

Comment: Вообще, может, стоит рассказать работодателю, что у Идеи есть Коммьюнити Эдишн? :)

Answer (score 2):

Перейдите к окну настроек по пути Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors: и уберите галочку с пункта "Show range indicator".